# How to cast a shape object?

Tags: vba, excel, type-conversion, shapes

I want to assign a `ComboBox` control to a class member of `ComboBox` type. This control is in a group on a worksheet.

The problem is through `GroupItems` property, I can only get a `Shape` object, not a `ComboBox`. So when assigning, it alerts "type mismatch".

If the control was not in a group, I could get an `OLEObject` object through `OLEObjects` property, and then use `Object` property to bypass the type mismatch. But what about now?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your Shape object, whether it is in a Group or not, you can access the ComboBox through the DrawingObject.Object property. So it would look something like

```
Set cboVariable = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).GroupItems(2).DrawingObject.Object
```